# Expandable List View - space between child and group views

Tags: java, android, xml, widget, expandablelistview

Im working on a simple to-do list app. I use `ExpandableListView` to display the tasks. From some reason, I keep getting a weird space between the group and child views. I tried setting divider height to `0dp` in the xml but it wouldn't change anything.

[screenshot of the space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbbme.jpg)

My xml code for the `ExpandableListView`:

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/myList"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/addTask"/>
```

EDIT:

**child view xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:background="#ff0000">



 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/displayDetails"
              android:text="@string/detailsChild"
              android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

**Parent view xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:background="#424242"
              android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:id="@+id/layoutCustom">

<View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:background="#FFFFFF"
      android:id="@+id/SpaceView"
      />


 <TextView
                android:layout_below="@id/SpaceView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/nameofcourse"
                android:id="@+id/course" android:layout_margin="10dp"/>


  <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/course"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>


<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/typeoftask"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/type" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textColor="#FE2E2E"
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:minWidth="20dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/SpaceView"     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

<ImageButton android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="50dp"
             android:id="@+id/mainEdit"
             android:src="@drawable/edit2"
             android:focusable="false"
             android:layout_below="@+id/date"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks guys and have a good week!

Comment: can you add `xml` files for child and group view ?

Comment: Edited the post and added

Comment: Could it be the header/footer divider? Try setting android:headerDividersEnabled = false in your ExpandableListView and see if that works.

Comment: Just tried that. Did not change anything.. :(

Comment: @baki1995 did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get what actually is the cause for this, when i tried your `layout` files, it did show the `divider` even when the `dividerHeight` was set to **0dp**, but setting some custom color to `android:divider` and setting the `dividerHeight` to **0dp** did remove the `white` space. I am pasting `xml` here, you can check yourselves and see if it helps,

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/myList"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:divider="#000" <!-- Use any color or drawable -->
      android:dividerHeight="0dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/addTask"/>
```